# Does with always run __exit__

Tags: python, exit, with-statement

I was wondering if the with statement's `__exit__` always executes, just like `finally`. Take this code:

```py
class WithTest(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print("entering")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print("exiting")

with WithTest():
    pass
```

Would it execute even when `exit()` is called in place of pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `__exit__` is executed when `exit()` is called. It won't exit when things like `os._exit` is called. This code:

```py
class WithTest(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print("entering")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print("exiting")

with WithTest():
    exit()
```

Would print:

```
entering
exiting
```